# Battery efficent VoIP software for Android

Tags: android, voip

I have VoIP provider that uses SIP to connect. And it uses UDP.

On my PC it ain't problem, but when I use it on an Android device, it eats battery very fast ([Zoiper](https://www.zoiper.com/) I tested).

Is there a more battery efficent program to use VoIP on a mobile device?